# how to always display empty tags, is there a css property for this?

Tags: css

for example empty `<pre>` tag is not displayed at all, it bevaves as it is not there. How to get rid of this problem withoud using a logic in underlying php. Visibility is not working.

Comment: If it's empty then what exactly is supposed to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see empty tags you can give them **width**, **height** and a **background color** with css. Note that some tags need the **display** property set to **block** so then can have a **height**, anchors for instance. I'm guessing you will be using this for debuging purposes, if not please clarify, maybe there is a more suitable solution.

```
a{
  display:block;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:red;
} 

<a href="http://google.com"></a> <!-- empty anchor tag -->
```

Comment: I think that the display:block is here a problem. I got tags that must be inline and are sometimes empty, and I see that there is no other solution to do it instead of php.

Comment: there are workaround for block value, you can also use "display:inline-block" although this does not work on Internet Explorer 6. You can also float the element "float:left", or position it absolute, it all depends on your needs.